# Detect word and make a shortcut action

Tags: shortcut, detection, voice

I want to create a programm that make something like this :

- I say a specific word
- The programm make a shortcut

EG : I say COPY the programm make CTRL+C

I see something like picovoice but not sure it works for my case.

Thank you